# PHP Oracle DB OCI Connection though and extended server

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface, tns

I have a web application which was written as PHP and makes some on an Oracle DB using OCI. My client now says that they don't want to have their database and related port directly accesible from outside. They want to have a second application server for this.

Is there a solution (application server) in which I can make my OCI connections with same syntax and connect to the database through it?

I mean, I need an external application installed on a different server which will redirect my database calls (OCI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is oracle's own solution for proxying: http://oracle.su/docs/11g/network.112/e10836/cman.htm

http://www.kernun.cz has also an sqlnet-proxy. (http://download.kernun.com/doc/handbook/sqlnet-proxy.8.html)

Or you can try to use simple tcp proxies. I used previously stunnel for example.
(I don't know how specific was my case, but it worked fine.)